# Double call in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm making this program to count the total price of items at a hypothetical store, and at the end I experience a double call. What is the best way to avoid this double call?

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
#Lukas Robin
#07.06.2021
class Stonk:
    def __init__(self, name ='', price = '', quantity = '', total = 0, shirtTotal = 0, sockTotal = 0, jeanTotal = 0):
        self.self = self
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.total = total
        self.shirtTotal = shirtTotal
        self.sockTotal = sockTotal
        self.jeanTotal = jeanTotal
    def main(__init__):
        __init__.name = ""
        __init__.total = 0
        __init__.shirtTotal = 0
        __init__.sockTotal = 0
        __init__.jeanTotal = 0
        __init__.price = {'shirts' : 25, 'socks': 12, 'jeans' : 50}
        __init__.name = input("Are you buying shirts, socks and/or jeans? ")
    def shirts(main, __init__):
        __init__.quantity = int(input("How many shirts would you like? "))
        __init__.shirtTotal = __init__.shirtTotal + (__init__.quantity*__init__.price['shirts'])
        print("The price of the shirts is, "+ str(__init__.shirtTotal))
        return __init__.shirtTotal
    def socks(main, __init__):
        __init__.quantity = int(input("How many socks would you like? "))
        __init__.sockTotal = __init__.sockTotal + (__init__.quantity*__init__.price['socks'])
        print("The price of the socks is, "+ str(__init__.sockTotal))
        return __init__.sockTotal
    def jeans(main, __init__):
        __init__.quantity = int(input("How many jeans would you like? "))
        __init__.jeanTotal = __init__.jeanTotal + (__init__.quantity*__init__.price['jeans'])
        print("The price of the jeans is, "+ str(__init__.jeanTotal))
        return __init__.jeanTotal
    main(__init__)
    options = __init__.name.split(", ")
    shirtTotals = shirts(main, __init__)
    sockTotals = socks(main, __init__)
    jeanTotals = jeans(main, __init__)
    for items in options:
        if items == ('socks' or 'sock'):
            socks(main, __init__)
        elif items == ('shirts' or 'shirt'):
            shirts(main, __init__)
        elif items == ('jeans' or 'jean'):
            jeans(main, __init__)
        __init__.total = shirtTotals+sockTotals+jeanTotals
        print("Your total is "+str(__init__.total))
```

(The question has been answered, thank you to everyone that helped.)

Comment: Are you purposefully trying to write hard to understand code? Why on earth are you using `__init__` and `main` as the names of the first arguments to your methods??

Comment: Anyway, is this accurately reflecting your indentation? Your problem is totally unclear from your description. Please see [ask] and the [help]

Comment: Sorry if the program is hard to understand, I'm a beginner with python. The problem is somewhere in lines 43-50 the functions are called twice, and I am wondering if there's any way to fix this?

Comment: That is not an adequate problem specification. **Again** please see the resources I linked above to help in writing a more clear question

Comment: Note, `if items == ('socks' or 'sock')` doesn't do what you *think* it does. `"socks" or "socks"` is equvalent to `"socks"`, you mean `if items == 'socks' or items == "sock"`

Comment: I recommend reviewing an online resource on how to write a class (e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) , which will be in the interests of a higher grade in the longer term, rather than getting through whatever coursework deadline you are working to now.

Comment: @RustyB I recommend against w3schools. Not a great resource. Better to just go to the [official tutorial/documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivilaga  For you and I, I would agree.  However, given the skill level of the OP (as evidenced by the code) I think the 'gentle intro' might get them off to a quicker start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is here:

```
options = __init__.name.split(", ")
shirtTotals = shirts(main, __init__)
sockTotals = socks(main, __init__)
jeanTotals = jeans(main, __init__)
```

`shirts()` `socks()` and `jeans()` are called no matter the result of `input("Are you buying shirts, socks and/or jeans? ")`

So the first repair I would make is to remove the duplicate of `shirts`, `socks` and `jeans`

So the bottom of code would look like this:

```
main(__init__)
options = __init__.name.split(", ")
for items in options:
    if items == ('socks' or 'sock'):
        socks(main, __init__)
    elif items == ('shirts' or 'shirt'):
        shirts(main, __init__)
    elif items == ('jeans' or 'jean'):
        jeans(main, __init__)
    __init__.total = shirtTotals+sockTotals+jeanTotals

print("Your total is "+str(__init__.total))
```

Even with these fixes, there is still the misuse of dunder methods.

**Dunder Methods**

Dunder methods or double underscore methods are special or magic methods that are never intended to be called directly. An Example of this is the `__init__` method.

If we were to create a new Stonk object we do not call `__init__` directly, instead, we call Stonk() then python will behind the scenes call `__init__` this keeps the code cleaner as we don't have init function call strewn though out the code, rather we see Stonk() which is much clearer.

Because of this, we must remove `__init__` from every place it does not belong.

Instead, we should replace it with `self` which refers to the current object.

With these changes, your code would look like this:

```
class Stonk:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.total = 0
        self.shirtTotal = 0
        self.sockTotal = 0
        self.jeanTotal = 0
        self.price = {'shirts': 25, 'socks': 12, 'jeans': 50}
        self.name = input("Are you buying shirts, socks and/or jeans? ")

    def shirts(self):
        quantity = int(input("How many shirts would you like? "))
        self.shirtTotal = self.shirtTotal + (quantity * self.price['shirts'])
        print("The price of the shirts is, "+ str(self.shirtTotal))
        return self.shirtTotal

    def socks(self):
        quantity = int(input("How many socks would you like? "))
        self.sockTotal = self.sockTotal + (quantity * self.price['socks'])
        print("The price of the socks is, " + str(self.sockTotal))
        return self.sockTotal

    def jeans(self):
        quantity = int(input("How many jeans would you like? "))
        self.jeanTotal = self.jeanTotal + (quantity * self.price['jeans'])
        print("The price of the jeans is, " + str(self.jeanTotal))
        return self.jeanTotal


stonk = Stonk() # creates new Stonk object

options = stonk.name.split(", ")

for items in options:
    if items == ('socks' or 'sock'):
        stonk.socks()
    elif items == ('shirts' or 'shirt'):
        stonk.shirts()
    elif items == ('jeans' or 'jean'):
        stonk.jeans()
    stonk.total = stonk.shirtTotals + stonk.sockTotals + stonk.jeanTotals
    print("Your total is "+str(stonk.total))
```

But we get an exception! `AttributeError: 'Stonk' object has no attribute 'shirtTotals'`

We if we compare the following blocks of code:

```
def socks(self):
    quantity = int(input("How many socks would you like? "))
    self.sockTotal = self.sockTotal + (quantity * self.price['socks'])
    print("The price of the socks is, " + str(self.sockTotal))
    return self.sockTotal
```

and:

```
for items in options:
    if items == ('socks' or 'sock'):
        stonk.socks()
    elif items == ('shirts' or 'shirt'):
        stonk.shirts()
    elif items == ('jeans' or 'jean'):
        stonk.jeans()
    stonk.total = stonk.shirtTotals + stonk.sockTotals + stonk.jeanTotals
```

We can see that `shirtTotals` does not match `shirtTotal`, and the same problem exists for `sockTotals` and `jeanTotals`. The fix here is the just change *Totals* to *Total*

Another improvement we could make is to take out reading input from the constructor. This is because it is unintuitive to read input in a constructor. With these 2 improvements your code would look like this:

```
class Stonk:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.total = 0
        self.shirtTotal = 0
        self.sockTotal = 0
        self.jeanTotal = 0
        self.price = {'shirts': 25, 'socks': 12, 'jeans': 50}

    def shirts(self):
        quantity = int(input("How many shirts would you like? "))
        self.shirtTotal = self.shirtTotal + (quantity * self.price['shirts'])
        print("The price of the shirts is, "+ str(self.shirtTotal))
        return self.shirtTotal

    def socks(self):
        quantity = int(input("How many socks would you like? "))
        self.sockTotal = self.sockTotal + (quantity * self.price['socks'])
        print("The price of the socks is, " + str(self.sockTotal))
        return self.sockTotal

    def jeans(self):
        quantity = int(input("How many jeans would you like? "))
        self.jeanTotal = self.jeanTotal + (quantity * self.price['jeans'])
        print("The price of the jeans is, " + str(self.jeanTotal))
        return self.jeanTotal

stonk = Stonk() # creates new Stonk object

options = input("Are you buying shirts, socks and/or jeans? ").split(", ")

for items in options:
    if items == ('socks' or 'sock'):
        stonk.socks()
    elif items == ('shirts' or 'shirt'):
        stonk.shirts()
    elif items == ('jeans' or 'jean'):
        stonk.jeans()

stonk.total = stonk.shirtTotal + stonk.sockTotal + stonk.jeanTotal
print("Your total is "+str(stonk.total))
```

With these minor fixes [we can see your code running here](https://www.online-python.com/HuhZeWOxrN)

**List of Edits I would consider making:**

[image: List of Edits I would consider making]

Comment: This is above and beyond the call of duty.  You deserve the 'mega-teacher' badge.